# Clustering combining numeric features and weekday & hour cyclic features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-scaling

The question is strictly related to
[What is a good way to transform Cyclic Ordinal attributes?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/what-is-a-good-way-to-transform-cyclic-ordinal-attributes/6335#6335)
and
[Ways to deal with longitude/latitude feature](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13567/ways-to-deal-with-longitude-latitude-feature?rq=1)

They presented a very clear answer about the approach to normalise hour variable and latlong variables.

The addition of this question is about how to approach normalization having both `weekday` and `hour` features. I wonder this because they are different granular level of the same information, hence, **strictly related.**

The objective is to run a k-means algorithm combining the normalised weekday and hour features with other traditional numeric features.

Comment: Iteratively, the answer should be applicable also by including `month`

Answer (score 1):

The essential transformation in @AN6U5's answer ist done in the following lines:

> df['hourfloat']=df.hour+df.minute/60.0
>   df['x']=np.sin(2.*np.pi*df.hourfloat/24.)
>   df['y']=np.cos(2.*np.pi*df.hourfloat/24.)

in the first line he transforms minutes into hours by dividing them by 60
so for example 20 Minutes are converted to 0.3333 hours

After that, in line 2 and 3 he converts this float number from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

So chaning this from hour to weekday you just need to adapt the first line.
Imagining a a clock where 00:00 is Monday, followed by Tuesday (clockwise), and so on ... you need to convert hour into weekday (for simplicity I assume weekday has the values 0-7). So first you divide your hour by 24 which transforms it into days and then further you divide it again by 7 which gives you a float number in weeks. Then add your weekday to the hour and then proceed with line 2 and 3 just as given, except that you correct the 24 to 7.

As a formula: hour/(24*7)+weekday = weekfloat
I haven't tried it out by myself but I think this should do it.

---

Alternatively, when you have two cyclic features you could transform weekday and hour into [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). This would leave you with three coordinates, x,y and z but also preserves the 'closeness' within one feature itself.

Comment: thank you sebastian. so you say that I should see the hour as the time since the beginning of the week.
But in this case it happens that 8 am of Monday is very far from 8 am of thursday, right?

Comment: True, they are 1 day appart, just as 06:52 and 07:52 are 1 hour appart in the other example. 
If you want to have the information of 8 am preserved I'd suggest you keep the column in your data.

Comment: thank you. what column are you suggesting to keep for preserving this information??

Comment: I assumed you have a column called "hour" which contains "8 am" in your previous scenario

Comment: clear yes I do. So maybe is better to use it as a numeric instead of converting using sincos

Comment: I think you have to try it out both ways, maybe it has even better results if you have both ways in your data set, even though it's a bit redundant information